# Screen blinked with black patches

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

Once in a while, in random instance, a portion of my screen (maybe half of it) will blinking black patches for a milisecond. This happened even when I'm not in a game, e.g. browsing Windows Explorer, using internet, etc. I can't seem to track when and why it happens, but it seems to happen more frequently when watching YouTube.

EDIT: This is what I mean by blinking black patches. Watch it slowly in the first few seconds... http://gfycat.com/SkeletalAdoredJanenschia

---

Might only be tangentially related, but there's also this weird continuous blinking every time I open this website: http://dragonporn.ldblog.jp/ (despite the name, it's not a weird fetish and 100% safe for work)

Here's a short video depicting what I meant: http://gfycat.com/CoarseQuarrelsomeDarwinsfox

Curiously other HTML5 video seems to be fine.

It's not exactly the same blinking with the one I've described before, but I'd lke to know if it's somehow related.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen if you plug in to an external display? Try updating your graphics chip driver.

Comment: @Jonah Not sure, haven't tried that. Last I checked all my drivers are updated..